# Insert css files to localhost

Tags: css, angularjs, import, localhost, load

For some reason, I could not get my files to load in my localhost. Trying different path solution but my error is still same. You can see from pictures my file-tree, where is index.file and css.folder with files. Any sugestions what to type in  to get my css files load. Thanks

Comment: Please show us the header line in which you include the `<link>` tag

Comment: This looks like an angular CLI application. Refer to the angular CLI documentation and add the relevant tags to your question instead of adding meaningless tags like `import` and `load`.

Comment: I also tried to set src/ direction ./css and other options, but, same goes always. @KobyDouek

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen ..thanks for suggestions.

Comment: @VladimirTomasevicMyNameIsVLT Please see my answer.

Comment: @KobyDouek Copied your answer, i am aware of path changes, but it won't load, i get same error..could it be something else?

Comment: The `GET` error you are getting - is it 404 ?

Comment: @KobyDouek No, no 404 ...its same as I posted pic, no changes.

Comment: @OK - So this is progress. If it's not 404, then the file is fetched but was not able to use it. Can you send me the CSS file via email ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151879/discussion-between-koby-douek-and-vladimir-tomasevic-mynameisvlt).

Comment: In a way, I founded solution... Opening file .angular-clo.json and included folder names so now it loads files.